# how do S1 ∈ S2, when R2 is not a subspace of R3?

Tags: linear-algebra

1. if dim(S2) = 3, S1 ⊂ S2, then what are the possible dimensions of S2?

Answer: 1, 2, 3

(this is from our quiz)

2. is R^2 a subspace of R^3?

Answer: R^2 is not a subspace of R^3 because its elements (2-component vectors) do not even come from R^3 (the set of 3-component vectors)

(this is from https://math.dartmouth.edu/~ahb/linalg/sol3.pdf)

My question is, S2 is a plane through origin right? Since it is the possible dimension, how R2 is not a subspace of R3?

We been debated about this for days, if you would kindly provide any hint to us, we will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I am greatly appreciated for everyone's reply. Sorry this is my first time posting and a few typo is already fixed.

Comment: What are S1 and S2? And the first question says "If dim(S2) = 3 [...], then what are the possible dimensions of S2", which seems a bit trivial.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Did you mean $\subset$ when you wrote $\in$?  I would say $\mathbb R^2$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ but isomorphic to one

Comment: Although $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, we say $\mathbb{R}^2$ is isomorphic to a 2-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: As for the first "half" of your question dealing with $S_1$'s and $S_2$'s, you seem to have made several typos or the question is meaningless or trivial.  Given the context, it seems as though you meant to ask "If $\dim(S_2)=3$ and $S_1$ $\color{red}{\text{is a subspace}}$ of $S_2$, then what are the possible dimension of $\color{red}{S_1}$?" to which the answer would be $0,1,2$ or $3$.  As for the second half of the question, the shortest answer is that to be a **sub**space of a space, one must not only be a vector space but also a *subset* but $\Bbb R^2$ is not a subset of $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote, "Since it is the possible dimension, how is $\mathbb R^2$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb R^3?$  "

Well, just because a vector space has the appropriate dimension

does not mean that it must be a subspace.

For example, polynomials of degree up to $3$ (alternatively, $2\times2$ matrices),

could be considered vector spaces of dimension $4$, but they are not contained in $\mathbb R^5$,

so they are not subspaces of $\mathbb R^5,$ though they may be isomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb R^5$.